# Accessing Class Name from Property Name

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, system.reflection

Consider this structure:

```
Name
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

Person
{
    public Name PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

I have the name of the `FirstName` property as a string. Now I want to use this string "FirstName" to get the name of the `Person` Class at runtime. I'm not sure if this is possible. Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if I follow.  You mean if you have an instance of Person such that `Person.PersonName.FirstName == "Bob"`, that somewhere you can have a method `Person FindPersonByName(string name)`, feed in "Bob" and it will return you the instance of the `Person` class in memory that was assigned "Bob" previously?

Comment: Or do you mean find the reference to all "Types" that somewhere in their property chain declare a property named "FirstName"?  Something like `FindTypesWithPropertyName("FirstName")` and it would return both `typeof(Name)` and `typeof(Person)`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a really strange requirement. That said, here's how you can do this:

```
// 1. Define your universe of types. 
//    If you don't know where to start, you could try all the  
//    types that have been loaded into the application domain.
var allTypes = from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
               from type in assembly.GetTypes()
               select type;

// 2. Search through each type and find ones that have a public  
//    property named "FirstName" (In your case: the `Name` type).    
var typesWithFirstNameProp = new HashSet<Type>
(
        from type in allTypes
        where type.GetProperty("FirstName") != null
        select type
);


// 3. Search through each type and find ones that have at least one 
//    public property whose type matches one of the types found 
//    in Step 2 (In your case: the `Person` type).
var result = from type in allTypes
             let propertyTypes = type.GetProperties().Select(p => p.PropertyType)
             where typesWithFirstNameProp.Overlaps(propertyTypes)
             select type;
```

Answer (score 1):

If all types are in a known one or more assembly, you can search in the assembly:

```
var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
var NameType = types.First(t => t.GetProperty("FirstName") != null);
var PersonType = types.First(t => t.GetProperties.Any(pi => pi.MemberType = NameType));
```

Comment: Good answer, but a small caution: if more than one type in the assembly has a property with that name, the type returned from types.First() may not be the one you expect. If all properties of all types have unique names, this isn't a problem.